# Multi-view DNS giving internal answers to external queries

Tags: bind, dns-hosting

I have a multi-view DNS configuration in BIND9, and I'm seeing really odd things. I've split my 4 zones between 2 views:

```
acl internals {
    192.168.88.0/24;
    localhost;
};

view "internal" {
  match-clients { "internals"; };

  zone ....
};

view "external" {
  match-clients { any; };

  zone ....
};
```

I've started getting reports that people are getting 192.168.88.x answers FROM OUTSIDE! Even Google (8.8.8.8) is providing 192-net addresses!! Looking at whatsmydns I confirm some nameservers are answering in the RFC1918 space. My zones have a 1W expire setting, and 30M TTL.

People are getting timeouts trying to connect to 192.168.88.x from the internet. :(  Can anyone offer any advice?

I have the root hint zone in the internal view. Does it also need to be in the external view as well?

Comment: So few information. Do you have secondary DNS server? Are the glue records the same as in the external domain zones? Show external zone config on primary and secondary DNS servers.

Comment: The root hint zone is necessary for a recursive nameserver, it has no use for an authoritative nameserver. So this has nothing to do with your problem. You should start by adding more logs and see your logfiles. Without your full configuration and the true names, it is next to impossible to really help you.